# rename the image name if uploaded twice?

Tags: php, jquery

I have uploaded an image and saved that  image to another folder it worked fine.But I want to change the image name if it already exists in the folder like if image.jpg already exists i need to rename it to image1.jpg and then to image2.jpg and so on.my code is

```
<?php
       $name = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
       $actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
       $original_name = $actual_name;
       $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      $i = 1;
      while(file_exists('upload/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
        {       
           $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
           $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
           $i++;
          /* code for uploading */

  }

   ?>
```

With this code i can able to change the filename to only image1.jpg if i upload image.jpg twice but if i uploadimage.jpg at third time it is not renaming as image3.jpg.I think the problem is around the loop i could not figure out it can any help me out to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that with this code someone could upload PHP files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
$actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$target = "upload/";

$i = 1;
while(file_exists($target.$actual_name.".".$extension)){       
    $actual_name = $original_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
}

$target = $target.basename( $name ) ; 
echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target) ? 
        "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been        uploaded"
        : "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since on each upload   $i is initialized to 1, so if file exists it will be saved as image2.jpg, on next upload also this repeats.
Loop for same file name exists in the directory and increment $i, then move uploaded file

Comment: It is not storing as image2.jpg. The loop is not goig to 2 it is always at 1 only.

Comment: Before moving file you need to rename the file as,
$name = $actual_name."($i).".$extension;

Comment: I got answer ajith the mistake i have stored the images from the while loop itself but if i write the same code after while loop it is working thanks to Michael Luthor for his response. And thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can use "File Upload by Unique Name"
   http://shwetabh.org/blog/file-upload-by-unique-name/